# Working with Strings and useState variables in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two useStates, which stores the values taken from the user.

```
const [classname, setClassname] = useState('');
const [name, setName] = useState('');
```

Similarly I have a string that has to be passed as body for the Rest API post request.

```
const string = '{ \ "class": "Device", \ "name": "some name", \ "instanceNumber": 0, \ 
                  "properties": [ \ \ ] \ }';
```

I have to pass the classname in place of device and and name in place of some name in the string. How can I change the string according to the useState values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Parse the string (JSON)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to an object, update the properties, [and then stringify it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). That way you're left with a clean string that doesn't have those escape backslashes.

```js
const className = 'Android';
const name = 'Max 2.0';

const str = '{ \ "class": "Device", \ "name": "some name", \ "instanceNumber": 0, \ "properties": [ \ \ ] \ }';

const obj = JSON.parse(str);

obj.class = className;
obj.name = name;

const json = JSON.stringify(obj);

console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use string interpolation for this, it is process of embedding an expression into part of a string:

```
const string = `{ \ "class":"${classname}", \ "name": "${name}", \ "instanceNumber": 0, \ 
                  "properties": [ \ \ ] \ }`;
```

Here is a reference to learn more https://dmitripavlutin.com/string-interpolation-in-javascript/

Comment: On posting this I get bad request error.

Comment: Updated the answer have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with string concatenation:

```js
const string = `{ \"class": ${classname}, \"name": ${name}, \"instanceNumber": 0, \"properties": [ \ \] \ }`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const string = `{ \ "class": ${classname}, \ "name": ${name}, \ "instanceNumber": 0, \ 
                  "properties": [ \ \ ] \ }`;
```

But if you are sending it to an api as a post request I would recommend sending it as a object as it would be easier to access the values in the backend.
As a object:

```
const string = { class: classname, name: name, instanceNumber: 0, properties: []};
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object with the desired properties and then stringify it using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and then send the stringified object with the `POST` request.

The example below takes two inputs from the user and then sends a stringified object as the `body` of the `POST` request.

```js
function App() {
  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState("");
  const [body, setBody] = React.useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title,
        body,
        userId: 1,
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => console.log(json));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input placeholder="Title" value={title} onChange={({ target }) => setTitle(target.value)} />
      <input placeholder="Name" value={body} onChange={({ target }) => setBody(target.value)} />
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```